# Creating a dummy variable based on the 75h percentile

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable, percentile

What I want to do is to construct a natural disaster dummy that takes the value 1 when the Damage-to-GDP ratio is above the 75th percentile, or, when this data is not available, to construct a natural disaster dummy that takes the value 1 when the Affected-to-total-population is above the 75th percentile. Can somebody give me a hint on how I can construct this in R?

Example of the dataset:

| Year | Country | Damage-to-GDP | Affected-people-to-total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | Tonga | 0.0102282455 | NA |
| 1990 | Samao | 0.5102296844 | NA |
| 1990 | Vanuatu | NA | 1.364508e-05 |

```r
> dput(data)

structure(list(Year = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L), Country = c("Tonga", 
"Samao", "Vanuatu"), Damage_to_GDP = c(0.0102282455, 0.5102296844, 
NA), Affected_people_to_total = c(NA, NA, 1.364508e-05)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: `quantile` should give you the relevant quantiles, and a simple `my_variable > value` should give you a dummy for one. Is this what you are struggling with?

Comment: Function `quantile` can identify percentiles, `cut` can encode into a factor variable (sometimes called dummy) and `ifelse` can be used to handle "some cases". Instead of `cut`you may also use `<` or `>` if you need only two groups.

To get a more detailed answer, please add an example data set.

Comment: Thank you! I added a picture which contains an example of the dataset

Comment: what do you want to do if both GDP and population are NA?

Comment: Those observations have been excluded. So it will not happen in this dataset anymore @Elia

Comment: @tpetzoldt I have added a picture which shows the dataset partly

Comment: Please don't use pictures for this, see Stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: you should post the output of `dput(your dataframe)` to share your data

Comment: See "DO NOT use images of code." in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

... but I see that you have NAs in. In that case, you can check for it with the `is.na()` function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I added a table of a part of the dataset now. @tpetzoldt

Comment: I shared it partly @Elia

Comment: Already better, but still not what we need. Please provide it in a format that is easy to paste in an editor. This helps us to help you.

I submitted an edit, let's see if it is accepted.

Comment: You could simply do: `dplyr::mutate(data, new_col= dplyr::coalesce(Damage_to_GDP, Affected_people_to_total)>0.75)`

Comment: @Onyambu on the dataset provided by the OP your solution return 3 FALSE, which is not the case, since the second observation has a Damage_to_GDP value > `quantile(Damage_to_GDP ,0.75,na.rm=T)`. So it should return F,T,F if I have understood the question well

Comment: @Elia change the 0.75 to the quantile value and you should have the correct results

Comment: @Onyambu This only gives me 2 TRUES in total, and I checked in excel and it should give me around 30 TRUES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `mutate` 75 percentile
2. apply conditions to generate newvar `case_when`
3. remove helper columns

```
library(dplyr)
options(scipen=999)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(qnt_75_Damage  = quantile(Damage_to_GDP, probs= 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
         qnt_75_Affected  = quantile(Affected_people_to_total, probs= 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(newvar = case_when(Damage_to_GDP > qnt_75_Damage ~ 1,
                            Damage_to_GDP == NA & Affected_people_to_total > qnt_75_Affected ~1)) %>% 
  select(-qnt_75_Damage, -qnt_75_Affected)
```

Output:

```
  Year Country Damage_to_GDP Affected_people_to_total newvar
1 1990   Tonga    0.01022825                       NA     NA
2 1990   Samao    0.51022968                       NA      1
3 1990 Vanuatu            NA            0.00001364508     NA
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L), Country = c("Tonga", 
                                                          "Samao", "Vanuatu"), Damage_to_GDP = c(0.0102282455, 0.5102296844, 
                                                                                                 NA), Affected_people_to_total = c(NA, NA, 1.364508e-05)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               -3L))
```

Comment: Hey! When I do this, I see in the tibble that is created that the new variable is created, but once I View(df), I don't see the newvar. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: `df1 <- df1 %>%...here the code.`  You have to assign to an object to be able to ``View(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

your example is sparse. Thus, the following results might not contain all the variants that you are looking for.

What you are describing is a comparison based on the 75th percentile of 2 of your data columns. As mentioned the `quantile()` function allows you to calculate the x-th percentile of a vector. With `{dplyr}` (and the `{tidyverse}` packages you can do that in a `mutate()` call. Then you construct a condition of your rule(s) and assign the dummy value 1. To avoid having to wrap multiple `ifelse()` calls, you can use dplyr's `case_when()`.

Good luck.

```
library(dplyr)

# data frame of test data - copied from SO with windows 
df <- structure(list(
    Year = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L)
  , Country = c("Tonga", "Samao", "Vanuatu")
  , Damage_to_GDP = c(0.0102282455, 0.5102296844, NA)
  , Affected_people_to_total = c(NA, NA, 1.364508e-05))
  , class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))

df

# for demonstration purposes we build the 75th percentile of
# Damage_to_GDP and Affected_people_to_total

df <- df %>%
  #-------------------- quantile comparison
  # function quantile can handle NAs, i.e. exclude them from the calculation
  # with probs you can set the quantile level you are looking for

  mutate( D_GDP_75 = quantile(Damage_to_GDP, probs = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)
         ,A_PPL_75 = quantile(Affected_people_to_total, probs = .075, na.rm = TRUE)
         ) %>%
  
  # What I want ... natural disaster dummy 
  # that ... value 1 
  # when the Damage-to-GDP ratio is above the 75th percentile
  # , or, 
  # when this data is not available ... and  
  # when the Affected-to-total-population is above the 75th percentile. 
  
  mutate( NAT_DIS_DUMMY = case_when(
     Damage_to_GDP > D_GDP_75 ~ 1  
    ,is.na(Damage_to_GDP) & Affected_people_to_total > A_PPL_75 ~ 1
    ,TRUE ~ as.double(NA)   # "default" return. check type
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit cumbersome but it should work and is a `base` solution. Since you did not provide a reproducible example I simulate some data:

```
set.seed(85)
df <- data.frame(gdp=sample(c(NA,runif(10)),100,replace = T),pop=sample(c(NA,runif(10)),100,replace = T))
summary(df)
#how many rows with both gdp and pop ==NA
sum(is.na(df)[,1]+is.na(df)[,2]==2)
#3rd quartile of gdp
quart3_gdp <- quantile(df$gdp,0.75,na.rm=T)
#3rd quartile of pop
quart3_pop <- quantile(df$pop,0.75,na.rm=T)

#first condition  if gdp > 3rd quartile then 1 else 0
df$dummy <- ifelse(df$gdp>quart3_gdp,1,0)
#second condition if dummy==NA and pop>3rd quartile then 1 else 0
df$dummy[is.na(df$dummy)] <- ifelse(df$pop[is.na(df$dummy)]>quart3_pop,1,0)
#remove both gdp and pop == NA
df <- df[!is.na(df$dummy),]
```

Comment: I don;t know why you have a lot of code. simply do `dplyr::mutate(df, new_col = +(dplyr::coalesce(gdp, pop)>0.75))`

Comment: Because is a `base` solution. However, without the data and the 3rd quartile variable creation this solution is two-line longer than the `dplyr` solution

Comment: if the rows with 2 NA are already removed, you do not need the last line of the example. For working with your dataset, just replace the column name with the column name of you variable

Answer (score 0):

The data set is a little bit too small and contains NAs, so it is difficult to test, but can may try something like this:

```r
data <- structure(
  list(
    Year = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L), 
    Country = c("Tonga", "Samao", "Vanuatu"), 
    Damage_to_GDP = c(0.0102282455, 0.5102296844, NA), 
    Affected_people_to_total = c(NA, NA, 1.364508e-05)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

# estimate precentiles
GDP75 <- quantile(na.omit(data$Damage_to_GDP), 0.75)
Aff75 <- quantile(na.omit(data$Affected_people_to_total), 0.75)

# replace NAs with zero
data[is.na(data)] <- 0

# check columns
disaster <- ifelse(data$Damage_to_GDP > GDP75, 1, ifelse(data$Affected_people_to_total > Aff75, 1, 0))
```

PS: use of **dplyr** would also be a good idea, but we don't know if this opens another thread.

Comment: Your solution return `c(1,1,0)` which is not the case for the example dataset provided by the OP

Comment: I had a copy and paste error in. Is fixed now.

Comment: Why do you do ifelse(data$Damage_to_GDP > Aff75)? Shouldn't this be ifelse(data$Affected-to-total-population > Aff75)?

Comment: Oh I see now that you corrected it, thank you, I will try it out!